# Вывод данных из массива php

Tags: php, массивы

Получаю массив данных в php:

```
print_r($fav_list2 = array_count_values($fav_list));
```

Получаю ответ:

```
Array ( ['18'] => 3 ['17'] => 1 )
```

Но никак не могу вывести эти данные по запросу, перепробовал много, смотрел как вывести массив, на специализированных сайтах, но не смог.

Как вывести ответ 3 и 1?

Comment: что вы имеете в виду под вывести 3,1 - вот это  `print_r(array_values($fav_list2 = array_count_values($fav_list)));` ?

Comment: 3 и 1 это какие-то значения массива?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обращайтесь к элементам массива по их ключам

```
echo $fav_list2['18']; // 3
echo $fav_list2['17']; // 1
```

**UPD**

Оказывается проблема была в том, что сами ключи содержат начальную и конечную одинарные кавычки, то есть обращаться к отдельному элементу следует так

```
echo $fav_list2["'18'"]; // 3
echo $fav_list2["'17'"]; // 1
```

Comment: Использовал ваш метод, ничего не выводиться при попытке заменить echo на print_r, то выводиться NULL

Comment: @JQUERYUSERS, вы в своем вопросе написали `print_r($fav_list2 = array_count_values($fav_list));`, а что выводит `print_r($fav_list2);`?

Comment: Я добавил и получил тот же ответ Array ( ['18'] => 3 ['17'] => 1 )

Comment: @JQUERYUSERS, могу только предположить, что ваши ключи содержать еще и сами кавычки. Попробуйте вывести `echo $fav_list2["'18'"];` и `echo $fav_list2["'17'"];`.

Comment: Спасибо, все работает!

Answer (score 0):

```
    foreach ($fav_list2 as $key => $value) {
    if ($key=18) {echo $value;} 
   }
```

Comment: Ваш метод работает, но мне надо будет именно послать POST запрос и вывести только нужный ответ с нужным id, а ваш метод выводит все значения

Comment: тогда использовать ответ данный выше. Он написан правильно. Или же обрабатывая все данные, а выводить только те, которые нужно. If ($key=18) {echo $value;}

Comment: Я понимаю, что метод правильный (echo $fav_list2['18']; // 3
echo $fav_list2['17']; // 1), но он не работает, поэтому и был создан данный вопрос, я до этого так пытался уже, я же написал, что изучил документацию по массивам php